# Why the SQL query is not working after addition of two new fields to the query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, time, unix-timestamp

I've following SQL query which is working absolutely fine .

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_login (user_id, email, password, token)
    VALUES ($user_id, '$email', '$user_password', '$token')";
```

Now I've added two new fields to the respective table called 'token_creation_time' and 'token_last_accessed_time'. These fields will contain the current time values(i.e. UNIX Time stamp values). For this purpose I used `time()` function from PHP in the SQL query as follows but it didn't work. I don't know where I'm making a mistake.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_login (user_id, email, password, token, token_creation_time, token_last_accessed_time)
    VALUES ($user_id, '$email', '$user_password', '$token', time(), '')";
```

The last two field's structure in MySQL DB is as follows :

```
Name : token_creation_time
Type : int(10)
Collation : 
Attributes :
Null : No 
Default : None
Extra : 

Name : token_last_accessed_time
Type : int(10)
Collation : 
Attributes :
Null : No 
Default : None
Extra :
```

In my query I want to insert the current time stamp value only into the field 'token_creation_time'.

Thanks.

Comment: Data type for the column token_last_accessed_time? Doesn't that column want a date/time value?

Comment: why is your datatype for time stamps are int? And you are trying to insert an empty string? try null (if column is nullable)

Comment: @jarlh:Since I'm storing the value in the form of UNIX Time stamp so no dat/time data type is required.

Comment: you inserting a literal string containing time() there. either a) use string concatenation to insert the actual timestamp. b) use pdo with a prepared statement (strongly preferred no matter what), or c) use mysql NOW() function instead of php time. a good way to debug that is to print the query statement out before you execute it, and then run it against the database directly, it will no doubt give you an error above shoving a string into an int or an unknown column

Comment: using NOW() function should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the Null:No to Null:Yes,it should work

```
Name : token_last_accessed_time
Type : int(10)
Collation : 
Attributes :
Null : Yes 
Default : None
Extra :
```

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered same error in postgresql when i try to insert an empty string '' for timestamps, so i use nullif function to overcome this:

```
NULLIF(?, '')
```

i think mysql has same function
AND make sure your column is nullable

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use php time() function inside query.

Either concatenate this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_login (user_id, email, password, token, token_creation_time, token_last_accessed_time)
VALUES ($user_id, '$email', '$user_password', '$token', ".time().", '')";
```

Or use mysql function UNIX_TIMESTAMP():

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_login (user_id, email, password, token, token_creation_time, token_last_accessed_time)
VALUES ($user_id, '$email', '$user_password', '$token', UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),      
'')";
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but can you please tell me why the below query is not working?
$sql = "UPDATE user_login SET token_last_accessed_time = ".time()." WHERE token = '$receivedToken'";
        $conn->query($sql);

Comment: If the reason is contained only in this query, it would be that it doesn't find  `token = '$receivedToken'` - maybe misspelled variable name? Just echo `$sql`, copy and paste to your database sql to check if it is that.

Answer (score 0):

You're inserting a literal string containing time() there.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_login (user_id, email, password, token,
token_creation_time, token_last_accessed_time)
VALUES ($user_id, '$email', '$user_password', '$token', time(), '')";
                                             error here ^^^^^^
```

either a) use string concatenation to insert the actual timestamp.

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO user_login (user_id, email, password, token, 
token_creation_time, token_last_accessed_time)
        VALUES ($user_id, '$email', '$user_password', '$token', " . time() . ", '')";
```

b) use pdo with a prepared statement (strongly preferred no matter what) to avoid sql injection attacks, or c) use mysql UNIX_TIMESTAMP() function instead of php time.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_login (user_id, email, password, token, 
token_creation_time, token_last_accessed_time)
    VALUES ($user_id, '$email', '$user_password', '$token', UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '')";
```

a good way to debug this is to print the query statement out before you execute it, and then run it against the database directly, it will no doubt give you an error above shoving a string into an int or an unknown column

Comment: Thanks for your help but can you please tell me why the below query is not working?
$sql = "UPDATE user_login SET token_last_accessed_time = ".time()." WHERE token = '$receivedToken'";
        $conn->query($sql);

Comment: can you please print the value of $sql, rather than just the code? it'll make life clearer. so will running mysql_error() to show the exact error message

Answer (score 0):

Change your table structure and set NULL attribute to Yes. It will work fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `now()` replace with `time()` it may work.